# Hook to a D3D11 process without Present and grab Texture2D

Tags: api, directx, hook, capture, apimonitor

I have some D3D11 process I am hooking to capture frames. If the process calls `Present()`, there is no problem to capture frame, but...
In some cases it has no visible window and no Present() method is called, but frame is really rendered. I can hook up `Draw()`, `ExecudeCommandList()` (and other) methods. Actually, there is no Present() called so I have no access to SwapChain's backbuffer. I suppose there is no SwapChain created when app is running w/o window.

When I hook `Draw()` or `ExecuteCommandList()`, I have access to `D3D11Device` and `D3D11DeviceContext` only.

Using API monitor I captured some information on D3D11 calls at the end of each frame:

[image]

Does anyone have any idea how can I get the resulting frame? My purpose is to get frame into D3D11Texture2D.

Thanks!

*UPD:*

I found that this method can be helpful for me: `ID3D11DeviceContext::ResolveSubresource`, but I can't handle hooking it. It is **amortized** (in main app I am trying to grab frame).

Part of VTable log:

```
[56]    5E225520    (CContext::TID3D11DeviceContext_GetResourceMinLOD_<1>)
[57]    5E1B95C0    (CContext::TID3D11DeviceContext_ResolveSubresource_Amortized<1>)
[58]    5E21DEC0    (CContext::TID3D11DeviceContext_ExecuteCommandList_<1>)
```

Thanks 2!

Comment: It seems like you are trying to hook an app that uses DirectComposition: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh437371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396. Are you trying to hook into Internet Explorer? DirectComposition doesn't issue Present calls. It sends (shares) the textures to DWM directly as far as I understand. You might need to hook DirectComposition or CreateTexture calls and try to gues when to capture the texture contents somehow.

Comment: No, It is d3d11 app with simple rendering transforms. This app stops calling `Present` if output window is not shown. It is 3d game middleware.
I tried hooking `CreateTexure2D`, but the best choice is `ResolveSubresource`. I can not hook it because it is **amortized** in main app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an access to ID3D11DeviceContext in any hooked D3D11 method, you can try calling [OMGetRenderTargets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476460(v=vs.85).aspx) method and get the resource from it:

```
ID3D11RenderTargetView *view = NULL;
pContext->OMGetRenderTargets(1, &view, NULL);
ID3D11Resource *pSourceResource = NULL;
view->GetResource(&pSourceResource);
```

Then you can save it to file as a Texture2D:

```
D3DX11SaveTextureToFile(pContext, pSourceResource, D3DX11_IFF_BMP, "image.bmp");
```

Or you can save Texture2D buffer on Output-Merger (OM) stage.